# ASP.NET Page is blank on postback, requires multiple page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

For some strange reason when I issue a post back (by clicking a button), the page performs the postback but the resultant page is completely blank. If I try to view page source I get a Confirm Form Resubmission message (using chrome).

However if I press f5 a few times, eventually the correct page will load.

I noticed that this usually happens when the button press causes some sort of database access. Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

EDIT: I noticed that this started happening more frequently when I added the following code however it's always been happening from time to time even before:

```
protected void BindPartList()
{
    if (UnitsDropDown.Text == "Imperial")
    {
        if (PartListGridView.Columns.Count > 4)
            PartListGridView.Columns.Remove(PartListGridView.Columns[4]);
        BoundField colIndex4 = new BoundField();
        colIndex4.DataField = "IMPUNITS";
        colIndex4.HeaderText = "Unit";
        colIndex4.SortExpression = "IMPUNITS";
        PartListGridView.Columns.Add(colIndex4);
        PartListGridView.DataSourceID = "ImpPartInfoObjectSource";
    }
    else
    {
        if (PartListGridView.Columns.Count > 4)
            PartListGridView.Columns.Remove(PartListGridView.Columns[4]);
        BoundField colIndex4 = new BoundField();
        colIndex4.DataField = "DWGUNIT";
        colIndex4.HeaderText = "Unit";
        colIndex4.SortExpression = "DWGUNIT";
        PartListGridView.Columns.Add(colIndex4);
        PartListGridView.DataSourceID = "MetricPartInfoObjectSource";
    }
    PartListGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Front end looks like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="PartListGridView" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    Width="100%" Font-Size="11pt" DataKeyNames="PARTNUM" AllowSorting="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PARTNUM" HeaderText="PARTNUM" SortExpression="PARTNUM"
            ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PARTDESC" HeaderText="PARTDESC" SortExpression="PARTDESC" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CATEGORY" HeaderText="CATEGORY" SortExpression="CATEGORY" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="COLOUR" HeaderText="COLOUR" SortExpression="COLOUR" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

in addition to the two datasources, of course

Thanks,

Comment: are you creating controls on the page dynamically? a little sample code goes a long ways too

Comment: Where do you call BindPartList() method from?

Comment: When you say it's returning a "blank screen", does that mean there is absolutely NO HTML at all being returned, or is there a head/body/form, etc, but just no datagrid?

Comment: @Scottie absolutely nothing on the page.

Comment: @M4N when i first load the page and when I change units

Comment: I would maybe try installing fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) and tracing what is coming in and what is going out.  Sometimes it will catch exceptions that the browser doesn't.

Comment: @Scottie i'm just testing this locally at the moment actually. Although, is it possible that this is caused by trying to retrieve too much info from the database? I noticed that the problem almost disappears when i use paging on my gridview.

Comment: Quite possibly.  If you are sending too much data across without paging, it can take minutes for your page to render.  When you view source, it appears as a blank page, but in reality, it's still just trying to render itself.